# for loop - 1st value in one list to 1st value second list

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, netmiko

```
list1=  ['a','b','c']
list2=  ['d','e','f']
```

I want to do for loop such that

Output:

```
"hi I am" + list1[1] + "is also" + list2[1]   i.e. Hi I am a is also d
"hi I am" + list1[2] + "is also" + list2[2]   i.e. Hi I am b is also e ....
"hi I am" + list1[3] + "is also" + list2[3]
```

Ignore the example :P*

Comment: What have you tried? You'll likely get better answers if you share specific code samples you've tried.

Comment: This appears to be homework from a tutorial on `for` loops.  s such, we expect you to post your coding attempt.  Please see [How to Ask a Homework Question]( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    print("hi I am " + list1[i] + " is also " + list2[i])
```

Comment: `size` needs to be changed to `len`.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about `zip`

```
for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
    print("hi I am " + i + " is also " + j)
#hi I am a is also d
#hi I am b is also e
#hi I am c is also f
```